# How to setup a Crew vs Crew online session in Grand Theft Auto Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

We have a long running GTA crew and we're trying to organise a crew vs crew session on GTA Online.

To setup a multi-crew session from Story Mode you go: **Pause Menu > Online > Play GTA Online > Crew Session**
[image]

Past that I have no idea what to do.

The most common answer I've found when Googling is to invite the other crew leader to an "Invite Only Session" - and then for them to invite the rest of the crew. But the crew leader for the other team is offline for a couple of weeks so that doesn't help.

How do I setup a Crew vs Crew online session in Grand Theft Auto Online?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but once you elect the number of crews you wish to have in this session, you should just be able to invite _anyone_ from another crew. Once that other crew member has joined, all the other members in that crew should be able to join their session (in Online mode: Menu > Friends > Join Friends session > Select friend in your session)

Comment: @Tas - thank you. I'll test this tonight and if it works I'll let you know.

Comment: @Tas - what you suggested worked. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you select the number of crews you wish to have participate and start the crew vs crew session, you only need to invite **anyone** from the crews you want to have join you. Once those single crew members have joined (you can of course invite multiple if you're aware of them), their crew members only need to join *their* session (which is your crew vs crew session) via: Online mode > Menu > Friends > Join Friends session > *crew member in your session*